# How do I render a parallax image using the flame game engine with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I am pretty new to the flame game engine built on top of flutter but I am wanting to render a parallax image for my background but when I try to render it in my main game class it won't show up?

```
class BackGround extends AnimationComponent {

  Rect backgroundRect;
  ParallaxComponent _parallaxComponent;
  BackGround() : super.empty() {
    backgroundRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      100,
      100,
      100,
      100,
    );
  }

  void render(Canvas c) {
    _parallaxComponent = ParallaxComponent([
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0010_1.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0009_2.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0008_3.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0006_4.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0005_5.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0003_6.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0002_7.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0001_8.png'),
      ParallaxImage('Layer_0000_9.png'),
    ], baseSpeed: Offset(100, 0), layerDelta: Offset(20, 0));
    _parallaxComponent.render(c);
  }
}
```

Here is what my main game class looks like.

```
class MainGame extends BaseGame with TapDetector, HasWidgetsOverlay {
  BackGround backback;
  Size screenSize;



  MainGame(this.storage) {
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    // resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());
    backback = BackGround();
  }

  void render(Canvas c) {
    backback.render(c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call the render method yourself, it is done for you when a `Component` is added to the game.
So like in the `ParallaxComponent` example [here](https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Parallax_Component), you `add` the component to the game like this:

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/parallax.dart';

class MyParallaxComponent extends ParallaxComponent<ComponentParallaxGame> {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    parallax = await gameRef.loadParallax(
      [
        ParallaxImageData('parallax/bg.png'),
        ParallaxImageData('parallax/mountain-far.png'),
        ParallaxImageData('parallax/mountains.png'),
        ParallaxImageData('parallax/trees.png'),
        ParallaxImageData('parallax/foreground-trees.png'),
      ],
      baseVelocity: Vector2(20, 0),
      velocityMultiplierDelta: Vector2(1.8, 1.0),
    );
  }
}

class ComponentParallaxGame extends BaseGame {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    add(MyParallaxComponent());
  }
}
```

And two other important thing to note are that components should be initialized in `onLoad` and not in the constructor, and that you already have a `size` on the `Game` class so you don't have to create your own `screenSize` variable like you do in your example. `size` is of the `Vector2` type, like most of such variables in Flame, and the width can be accessed with `size.x` and the height with `size.y`.

It also seems like you might using Flame `0.26.4`, I recommend that you use `1.0.0-releasecandidate.13` instead since it is much more mature and it is the code base that is being actively developed (don't fear the `releasecandidate` tag, we will quite soon release `1.0.0`).

Comment: Thanks @spydon! It works now and I’ll be looking forward to release 1.0.0